# Xor Different between Java and Flash Actionscript

Tags: java, actionscript, xor

I currently writing a Java to simulate the return value like Flash ActionScript.

Here is the problem I got both application return different value.

Under ActionSript 3.0

```
k = 942945590;
z = 3180323136;

trace(k ^ z);
```

the result will return  "-2051287946"

When i try to do it in Java.

```
    long k = 942945590L;
    long z = 3180323136L;
System.out.println (k ^ z);
```

the result return positive value instead "2243679350"

Any idea how can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's the same result but different representations, because your Java `long`s are 64 bit whereas presumably in Actionscript you are working with 32 bit arithmetic:

```
-2051287946 ==         0x85BBD476 (32 bit signed 2's complement)
 2243679350 == 0x0000000085BBD476 (64 bit signed 2's complement)
```

If you want the results to match then use `int` instead of `long` in the Java code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like ActionScript is either doing the calculation in 32-bit arithmetic or, more likely, the `trace()` statement is formatting the result as if it were 32 bit.